# Is my truth table right?

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

I make a truth table for this question

is it right??

Comment: The top part is right. But then the bottom part isn't.

Comment: what is botton part???  100 101 110 111 ???

Answer (score 0):

All of your Out states are correct, but you need to add up/down M as an output.

First 4 states would be:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
M & State & M & Out  \\ \hline
0 & 00 & 0 & 01 \\ \hline
0 & 01 & 0 & 10 \\ \hline
0 & 10 & 1 & 11 \\ \hline
0 & 11 & X & XX \\ \hline
\end{array}